# What kind of model can be used to simulate over- and under voltage in a Li-Battery pack?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, matlab, modeling

So far I have not much experience with modeling in the field of lithium-ion cells or batteries except equivalent circuit models (ecm)-models which I've implemented and used for simulations in Matlab/Simulink (using the Simscape toolbox not Simscape battery) and would say I'm familiar with.
As far as I know or observed these models already have a certain inaccuracy at the limits e.g. SOC >80% and SOC <20% (inaccuracy is strongly related to environment conditions temperature and also to aging).
Further I've observed that the above Matlab toolbox allows -at least it delivers a result- in case a battery was over discharged SOC <0 while it would cap the SOC if the value is > 100%. However, the voltages behave decreasing or increasing in both cases, as physically expected.
Honestly I'm doubting the results and therefore would strongly assume that an ecm model is the wrong choice for simulating an over- or under-voltage or an over charge or discharge, which both could happen due to circuits in case of a thermal propagation and/or abuse tests which is a topic I'm trying to study and simulate.

I also had in mind a solution that seems more complicated to me and consists in replacing the 1RC or 2RC ECM models for which the Matlab toolbox already offers a useful model that only needs to be parameterized by the physical equivalent circuit. In this case, however, the calculation of the battery properties would lead me to my limits (I am far from an expert in electrical engineering, my field is rather modeling and simulation) and I think building such a model for a battery pack will take extremely long time costs.

For the above reasons I'm looking for a suitable model and an explanation how and why it would fit. The model needs to have an acceptable accuracy for the voltages and current in the pack and it should allow to display SOC for over- and under charging.